# Use document.createElement instead of contentDocument.createElement in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = 'test';
iframe.name = 'test';
iframe.src = 'about:blank';
iframe.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    var iframeBody = iframeDoc.body;
    console.log(document === window.top.document);
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://example.com/test.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    iframeBody.appendChild(script);
}, false);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

what's the potential problems of using `document.createElement` instead of using `iframe.contentDocument.createElement` in iframe?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: I had a kind of feeling this might cause some problems.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you want to know this if `iframe.contentDocument.createElement` already works. Is there some benefit to using `document.createElement`?

Comment: Because my workmate used `document.createElement` by mistake and it works in production.And I want to know potential problems curiously:)